# How do i find row from cell content click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<tr id="autogeneratedrowid_gridrow1">
    <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <table id="unitprice"> 
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <A class=link2 id="aurogenerated" onclick="setMode(this); return false;">Edit</A>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr id="autogeneratedrowid_gridrow2">
.....
.....
</tr>
```

This is my rendered html code when i click on link button setMode function is called & i m passing 'this' means link button to the function I want to find gridrow when link button is click using Jquery?
I am using this

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

but this is not a right way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your ids are autogenerated, you could do this:

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).closest("table").closest("tr");
```

What `closest` does, is to find the closest antecessor that matches the selector.

**EDIT**:
My above solution solves your problem. But a better solution (if you can change the html markup), would be to add a class to your all your row `tr`s, lets's say 'rowClass', like this:

```
<tr id="autogeneratedrowid_gridrow1" class='rowClass'>
```

And then your selector would be this:

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).closest(".rowClass");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: but my id is autogeneated how can i add a class to it? thanx

Comment: The id doesn't matter, it will remain as is. You have to add to the `tr` a **class** attribute with value 'rowclass', so you have `<tr class="rowClass" ... >`

Answer (score 0):

you can use closeset

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).parent().closest('tr')
```

Comment: This will find the `tr` in the seventh line of the code (wrong)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.link2').closest('table').closest('tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).parents('tr').index());
```

This code will give the index of the row, hope this will help you.